# How to make a wrap in the output with a nested lists

Tags: list, nested, nested-lists, python-3.5

I have this nested list in my Output:

```
[['O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O'], ['O',
'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O'], ['O', 'O',
'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']]
```

How can I bring it in this form:

```
[

['O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O'], 

['O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O'], 

['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']

]
```

In other words: How can I make a wrap in a for-loop ?

For example:

```
for i in range(3):
   my_list.append(i)
   # How to make now a wrap ?
```

Answer (score 1):

`pprint.pprint` gives a nicely formatted output:

```
>>> L = [['O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O'], ['O',
          'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O'], ['O', 'O',
          'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']]

>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(L)
[['O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O'],
 ['O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O'],
 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']]
```